# JSON pretty print multiple lines

Tags: python, json

which command line utility can pretty-print a file with multiple lines (each encoded in json)

input file: msgs.json:

```
[1,{"6":7,"4":5}]
[2,{"6":7,"4":5}]
```

it seems that json.tool works only with a single JSON message

EDIT: modified [json.tool](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/8a3b5bfd266e4168491dec453e76f37c711605d2/lib-python/2.7/json/tool.py) to support multiple JSON msgs in the answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21149875/165130)

example usage:

```
python myjson.py msgs.json
                    [
                        1,
                        {
                            "4": 5,
                            "6": 7
                        }
                    ]
                    [
                        2,
                        {
                            "4": 5,
                            "6": 7
                        }
                    ]
```

Comment: Please give an example for your "multiple json lines".

Comment: It is probably just invalid JSON. Remember that JSON, like XML, can only have one *root* value. Thus the text data `{"a":1}{"b":2}` is invalid JSON and the object that contains `b` is "Extra data".

Comment: In particular, it probably _is_ in a (quasi-)standard format, either multi-JSON (multiple JSON objects following each other directly, like the JSON-RPC wire protocol), or JSON-lines (multiple JSON objects, all without any unescaped newlines, separated by newlines). Python doesn't have a built-in parser for either of those two formats, but it's incredibly trivial to write your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

myjson.py - a modified json tool to support multiple JSON messages:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

"""myjson.py: Command-line tool to validate and pretty-print JSON

Usage::
     1)     $ echo '{"json":"obj"}' | python myjson.py
        {
            "json": "obj"
        }
     2)     $ echo '{ 1.2:3.4}' | python myjson.py
        Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 2)

     3) printing a file with multiple lines where each line is a JSON message:
            e.g. msgs.json:
                    [1,,{"6":7,"4":5}]
                    [2,{"6":7,"4":5}]
            python myjson.py msgs.json
                    [
                        1,
                        {
                            "4": 5,
                            "6": 7
                        }
                    ]
                    [
                        2,
                        {
                            "4": 5,
                            "6": 7
                        }
                    ]
"""
import sys
import json
def main():
        data = []
        if len(sys.argv) == 1:
            infile = sys.stdin
            outfile = sys.stdout
        elif len(sys.argv) == 2:
            infile = open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')
            outfile = sys.stdout
        elif len(sys.argv) == 3:
            infile = open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')
            outfile = open(sys.argv[2], 'wb')
        else:
            raise SystemExit(sys.argv[0] + " [infile [outfile]]")
        with infile:
            try:
                  for line in infile:
                            data.append(json.loads(line))
            except ValueError, e:
                raise SystemExit(e)
        with outfile:
            for d in data:
                    json.dump(d, outfile, sort_keys=True,
                             indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
                    outfile.write('\n')
if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Answer (score 9):

In python do something like this:

```
import json

with open('msgs.json', 'r') as json_file:
    for row in json_file:
        data = json.loads(row)
        print(json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True, indent=2, separators=(',', ': ')))
```

Answer (score 4):

`jq` can do this and a lot more, it's what I use but may be overkill for you.
You can find it [here](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

`cat yourfile.json | jq '.'` should do the trick

Comment: it throws errors on special characters (like quotes) which are part of the json msg

Comment: are you sure the quotes are escaped correctly and not smartquotes?

Comment: the quotes in the input are not escaped, the expectation is that json tool takes care of it

Answer (score 1):

A command line utility to pretty-print a line-delimited JSON file (aka NDJSON, LDJSON, JSON Lines, JSON-L, JSONL) that is available for anyone with a modern version of Python:

```bash
python -m json.tool msgs.json --json-lines
```

[jq](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/) is more powerful and flexible beyond just pretty-printing, so it it's worth [installing](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/download/) and using it like this:

```bash
cat msgs.json | jq .
```